# Using bash command in Python Module

Tags: python, module, wget

I have been trying to write a FUNCTION (To be added in a MODULE) where I need to use "wget" command in bash-mode. e.g. I have this line with in my function,

```
href_aw =  search_str_1 + collections[1]+ search_str_2 + str(RA) + '+' +  str(Dec) + search_str_3 

!wget -O url_list_dir/wise_allsky.dat "{href_aw}" --no-check-certificate
```

this works fine as long as I have this in a function. I can execute it and get desired file downloaded.
 When I copy pasted my function in a module and tried calling it, I get an error message

> " File
>   "/Users/aprakash/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/lib/python3.5/WISE_photometry_abhi.py",
>   line 67
>
> !wget -O url_list_dir/neo_wise.dat "{href_nw}" --no-check-certificate
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

So, after browsing some internet (stackoverflow) I changed my wget command to following;

```
import os 
os.system("wget -O url_list_dir/wise_allsky.dat '{href_aw}' --no-check-certificate")
```

but this is returning an empty file. Any ideas how to fix this? Please note that I can't use python wget module and a command like this;

```
wget.download(mask_3b, out = img_dir)
```

since it doesn't allow for keywords like "--no-check-certificate" which I have to use.

I don't understand how if something is working perfectly fine as a functions give an error only because it is being called from a module. I would like to repeat that the first command works fine if I use the function in the same script where it is written.

Thanks for your help!
Abhi

Comment: Please dormat your code as code (`{}` icon) and not as a quotation.

Comment: First, why can't you use `requests` for this instead of shelling out to `wget`? Second, even if you need `wget`, why do you need the bash shell instead of just calling `wget` directly? And, either way, why are you using `os.system` instead of `subprocess.run`? Meanwhile, what were you expecting `!wget -O url_list_dir/wise_allsky.dat "{href_aw}" --no-check-certificate` to do? Python doesn't have any kind of `!` syntax for running commands.

Comment: Also, just putting `{href_aw}` into your string literal won't cause any kind of substitution; you need to use an f-string (prefix the string literal with `f`), or call `format_map` or `format` on the string, or do _something_.

Comment: @abarnert  shelling out to wget? The website I am reaching out to suggests "wget" as the API. "what were you expecting?" I get an output file which looks like a TSV containing bunch of information. Like I said, this works fine in a function. "Also, just putting {href_aw} into your string literal won't cause any kind of substitution?" This allowed me to put the variable string "href_aw" in wget command, which I was not able to do directly. That worked, not sure about your "!" comment since that worked as well.

Comment: Well, you haven't told us what website you're using, so there's no way anyone can read what they've said there. But meanwhile, what about all of the other questions?

Comment: http://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/ibe/sia.html

Comment: @abarnert Please look at this page "https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html". In section; "System shell commands" that explains the use of "!" in python.

Comment: @Abhishek That’s not a feature of Python, it’s a feature of the iPython shell.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, I realize that now. I need to change that line with a python feature. OS.system was an effort in that direction. I have not used subprocess before, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this. The above task can be accomplished in few lines using "requests", 'io' and "pandas". Thanks for all the comments though, they were useful and I had not even heard of "request".

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io
href_aw =  search_str_1 + collections[1]+ search_str_2 + str(RA) + '+' +  str(Dec) + search_str_3 
r_aw  = requests.get(href_aw)
df_aw = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r_aw.text))   
df_aw.to_csv(url_list_dir+'wise_allsky.dat')
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try subprocess instead of os.system, so something like this:

```
import subprocess
bashCommand = "wget -O url_list_dir/wise_allsky.dat '{href_aw}' --no-check-certificate"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```